# Apigee: Server Error. Bundle size is greater than the 15 MB. Use large resources at organization/environment level

Tags: apigee

When i tried to add "Add-CORS" Assign message policy to an existing API proxy i got this Error repeatedly.
I tried to undeploy and re-deploy the App but none worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is issue is because of bundle size and not because of CORS policy. Check if bundle size can be reduced. Or else please log a ticket with support to get help on the resolution of the bundle size.

Answer (score 0):

It is something to do with the package size. If you are using NodeJS to develop your bundle:

1. Reduce your API Proxy bundle size by removing unnecessary files and un-used modules.
2. Import resources separately through the [Management API](http://apigee.com/docs/management/apis/post/organizations/%7Borg_name%7D/apis/%7Bapi_name%7D/revisions/%7Brevision_number%7D)
3. [Run NPM install on the server](http://apigee.com/docs/management/apis/post/organizations/%7Borg_name%7D/apis/%7Bapi_name%7D/revisions/%7Brevision_num%7D/npm) through the Management API

*[Replace the placeholders in URL with actual value]*

See the discussion [**here**](https://community.apigee.com/questions/4706/when-i-tried-to-add-add-cors-assign-message-policy.html).